# how to make generic retrofit library for api calling

Tags: android, retrofit

i'm working on API integration. i want to make generic class for API integration. which can comfortable with for all API integration.right now i'm using separate code for all API. i'm new in android application development. so please guide me.

```
 public void getHomeCategoryDetailApi(Context context) {
    final ProgressDialog loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please wait", "Loading...");
    Retrofit restAdapter = ApiLists.retrofit;
    ApiLists apiCall = restAdapter.create(ApiLists.class);
    Call<HomeCategoryModelClass> call = apiCall.homePageCatListAPI();
    Log.d(TAG, "CategoryDetail : " + call.request()+" \n"+apiCall.homePageCatListAPI().toString());

    call.enqueue(new Callback<HomeCategoryModelClass>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<HomeCategoryModelClass> call, Response<HomeCategoryModelClass> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: CategoryDetail:" + response.body());
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse:  response.code():" + response.code());
            if (response.body() == null) {
                loadingDialog.dismiss();
                globalClass.showAlertDialog(getActivity(), getString(R.string.InternetAlert), getString(R.string.InternetMessage), false);
            } else {
                loadingDialog.dismiss();
                if (response.body().getStatusCode().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    homeCategoryImageMenu = (ArrayList<Menu>) response.body().getMenu();
                    thirdHorizontalRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    globalClass.showAlertDialog(getActivity(), "Alert", "" + response.body().getStatus(), false);
                }
            }
            if (response.errorBody() != null) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: response.errorBody()===>" + response.errorBody().string());
                    if (loadingDialog.isShowing() && loadingDialog != null) {
                        loadingDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<HomeCategoryModelClass> result, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + result.toString());
            loadingDialog.dismiss();
            globalClass.showAlertDialog(getActivity(), getString(R.string.InternetAlert), getString(R.string.InternetMessage), false);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Create a Utility Network class and use `Interface` for callback.

Comment: i want to make like this .i just pass some require parameter

Answer (score 6):

Here is Bast Way to call API

```
public class APIResponse {
private static String TAG = APIResponse.class.getSimpleName();

public static <T> void callRetrofit(Call<T> call, final String strApiName, Context context, final ApiListener apiListener) {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
            if (strApiName.equalsIgnoreCase("LoginApi")) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body().toString());
                    //  NearByNurse nearByNurse = (NearByNurse) response.body(); // use the user object for the other fields
                    // apiListener.success(url,nearByNurse);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                } else {
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.errorBody().string());
                        apiListener.error(strApiName, response.errorBody().string());
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else if (strApiName.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                //Patient user = (Patient) response.body();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.toString());
            if (strApiName.equalsIgnoreCase("searchNearbyTest")) {
                apiListener.failure(strApiName, t.toString());
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

In API Calling Side

```
private void loginApi() {
    Retrofit retrofit = ApiLists.retrofit;
    ApiLists apiList = retrofit.create(ApiLists.class);
    Call<JsonElement> loginApiCall = apiList.loginApi("kjdf", "fkldngdkl", "lkfdxngl", "kjngn", "jksdgkj");
    APIResponse.callRetrofit(loginApiCall, "LoginApi", LoginActivity.this, this);
}
@Override
public void success(String strApiName, Object response) {
    if (strApiName.equals("LoginApi")) {
    }
}

@Override
public void error(String strApiName, String error) {
    if (strApiName.equals("LoginApi")) {

    }
}

@Override
public void failure(String strApiName, String message) {
    if (strApiName.equals("LoginApi")) {

    }
```

and interface call on API response.

```
public interface ApiListener {
void success(String strApiName, Object response);
void error(String strApiName, String error);
void failure(String strApiName, String message);
 }
```

Comment: what is ApiLists?

Comment: Api list is interface, In which all api call mention.

Answer (score 2):

This's my common function basic call Api.java

```
public class Api {
private void basicCall(Call<DataResponse> call) {
    if (call == null) {
        listener.onResponseCompleted(Config.STATUS_404, "404 not found", null);
        return;
    }
    call.enqueue(new Callback<DataResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<DataResponse> call, @NonNull Response<DataResponse> response) {
            int code = response.code();
            //Check http ok
            if (code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                //Check status
                if (response.body().getStatus() == Config.STATUS_OK) {
                    //Everything's OK
                    listener.onResponseCompleted(Config.STATUS_OK, response.body().getError(), response.body().getData());
                } else {
                    listener.onResponseCompleted(Config.STATUS_FAILED, response.body().getError(), null);
                }
            } else if (code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                try {
                    ErrorResponse error = Api.gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().string(), ErrorResponse.class);
                    listener.onResponseCompleted(Config.STATUS_401, error.getError(), error.getData());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                listener.onResponseCompleted(Config.STATUS_404, "404 not found", null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<DataResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            listener.onResponseCompleted(Config.STATUS_404, "404 not found", null);
        }
    });
}
//And you can use
public void getProductList(OnResponseCompleted listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
    Call<DataResponse> call = apiService.getProductList();
    basicCall(call);
}
}
//or orther function
```

This's ApiService.java

```
public interface ApiInterface {
 @POST("product/list")
 Call<DataResponse> getProductList();
}
```

This's OnResponseCompleted.java

```
public interface OnResponseCompleted {
void onResponseCompleted(int status, String error, Object data);
}
```

Comment: what is data response here, I'm using different model class in every api so how can i manage it

Answer (score 1):

i want to make like this .i just pass some require parameter....

```
public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message,
                            Boolean status) {

    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

   alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Set Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    if (status != null)
        // Set alert dialog icon
        alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.ic_success : R.drawable.ic_fail);

    // Set OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    // Show Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Yeah yeah we got it . Now remove this .

Comment: OMG , Very nice answer  :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..
In this code Retrofit object set up done in one class and all api calling into interface..

```
public class ApiClient {
private final static String BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com";

public static ApiClient apiClient;
private Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static ApiClient getInstance() {
    if (apiClient == null) {
        apiClient = new ApiClient();
    }
    return apiClient;
}

//private static Retrofit storeRetrofit = null;

public Retrofit getClient() {
    return getClient(null);
}


private Retrofit getClient(final Context context) {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    return retrofit;
}
}
```

after that call the api into api interface..

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@GET("{affenpinscher}/images")
Call<Product> getProductData(@Path("affenpinscher") String breed);
@GET("getProductDetailByProductId?ProductId=3")
Call<JsonObject> ITEM_DESCRIPTION_RESPONSE_CALL();

@POST("linke")
Call<Response> passJsonData(@Body JsonData jsonData);

@GET("/users/waadalkatheri/repos")
Call<Response> getdata();
}
```

and when you call api in activity or fragment used below code..

```
ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getInstance().getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<ResponseData> responseCall = apiInterface.getdata();
    responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseData> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseData> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null && response != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GetData" + response.body().getLanguage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseData> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Errror", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```