# How to achieve MVVM + Live Data with retofit generic Api call in Android?

Tags: mvvm, retrofit2, android-livedata, android-mvvm, mutablelivedata

I want to create retrofit2  generic Api call in MVVM  Architechture. I have not found  any proper tutorial regardng this topic. I have done MVVM Architecture successfully . but I want to make Retrofit Api call generic through out the Application .Please help me out.

here is my code  Repository

```
public class MainRepository {

   // private List<ContactList> users = new ArrayList<>();
    private MutableLiveData<ContactList> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private Application application;

    public MainRepository(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<ContactList> getMutableLiveData() {

        Retrofit retrofit = ApiClient.getClient();
        ApiListInterface apiListInterface = retrofit.create(ApiListInterface.class);

        Call<ContactList> call = apiListInterface.getContacts();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ContactList>(){


            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ContactList> call, Response<ContactList> response) {

                ContactList contactLists = response.body();
                if (contactLists != null ) {
                   // users = (List<ContactList>) contactLists.ge;
                    mutableLiveData.setValue(contactLists);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ContactList> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.d("ListSize"," - > Error    "+ t.getMessage());

            }
        });

        return mutableLiveData;
    }

}
```

here is my ViewModel class

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private MainRepository mainRepository;

    public MainViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        mainRepository = new MainRepository(application);
    }
    public LiveData<ContactList> getAllUsers() {
        return mainRepository.getMutableLiveData();
    }

}
```

Here is My all  Model class

```
public class ContactList {

    @SerializedName("contacts")
    @Expose
    private List<Contact> contacts = null;

    public List<Contact> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }

    public void setContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

}


public class Contact {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("address")
    @Expose
    private String address;
    @SerializedName("gender")
    @Expose
    private String gender;
    @SerializedName("phone")
    @Expose
    private Phone phone;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Phone getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(Phone phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

}


public class Phone {

    @SerializedName("mobile")
    @Expose
    private String mobile;
    @SerializedName("home")
    @Expose
    private String home;
    @SerializedName("office")
    @Expose
    private String office;

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getHome() {
        return home;
    }

    public void setHome(String home) {
        this.home = home;
    }

    public String getOffice() {
        return office;
    }

    public void setOffice(String office) {
        this.office = office;
    }

}
```

Here is My Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MainViewModel mainViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);

        getUserList();



    }

    private void getUserList() {

        mainViewModel.getAllUsers().observe(this, new Observer<ContactList>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ContactList contactLists) {

                Log.d("contacts_list",contactLists.getContacts().toString());

            }
        });



    }


}
```

Comment: what do you mean by generic API

Comment: I want to mean generic  Api call , that means  your  entire  Apllication Api call should have single Entry point , or single class to maintain Api call, you can see an example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48921846/how-to-make-generic-retrofit-library-for-api-calling